# RDD of CassandraRow not working with take-command - why?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am doing some exercises of the DataStax VM.

A CassandraTable is given and I shall do some filtering and retrieving the top 5 elements using Spark API functions rather than cassandra-query-functions.

There I am doing the following:

```scala
val cassRdd = sc.cassandraTable("killr_video", "videos_by_year_title")
val cassRdd2 = cassRdd.filter(r=>r.getString("title") >= "T")
println("1" : + cassRdd2)
println("2" : + cassRdd2.count)
println("3" : + cassRdd2.take(5))
println("4" : + cassRdd2.take(5).count)
```

Results in:

- 1: MapPartitionsRDD[185] at filter at :19
- 2: 2250
- 3: [Lcom.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow;@56fd2e09
- 4: compile Error (missing arguments for method count in trait
  TraversableOnce

What I have expected:

- 1: and 2: work as expected
- 3: returns only one row? I would expect a RDD of 5 cassandra Rows
- 4: this isn't the rdd count after 3:, hence I didn expect it to work,
  looks like its some kind of cassandraRow-count-method I was not
  intended to call

The solution given by Datastax uses the RDD and does a map-transformation on it, to only take the title and on that new title-rdd it does the filtering and the take-command.

Ok, works, but I don't understand, why take does not work on a RDD-of CassandraRow or what the result of that may be.

```scala
val cassRdd2 = cassRdd.map(r=>r.getString("title")).filter(t >= "T")
```

I thought the take-command on any RDD (regardless its contents) would do always the same, taking the first x elements resulting in a new RDD of the exact same type with a size of x elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rdd.take(n)` actually moves `n` elements to the driver and returns them as an array, see [ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@zipPartitions[B,C,D,V](rdd2:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[B],rdd3:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[C],rdd4:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[D])(f:(Iterator[T],Iterator[B],Iterator[C],Iterator[D])=%3EIterator[V])(implicitevidence$25:scala.reflect.ClassTag[B],implicitevidence$26:scala.reflect.ClassTag[C],implicitevidence$27:scala.reflect.ClassTag[D],implicitevidence$28:scala.reflect.ClassTag[V]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[V]). If you want to print them:

```
println("3" : + cassRdd2.take(5).toList)
```

or `cassRdd2.take(5).foreach(println)`. The last line does not work as the method is called `length` (or `size`) for arrays:

```
println("4" : + cassRdd2.take(5).length)
```

Comment: thanks, that also answers my next question in my own answer (belowe), the actions result is an array

Answer (score 0):

I mixed something up:

`take` is an action, I shouldn't expect a RDD (but what is it? some binary? does it have a name? some kind of collection? may also a single Value like String or int if it fits)

On that I shouldn't use `count` as used to do on RDDs, rather I should use `size` as used to do on java-collections. By the way, `count` is also an action, using an action after an action sound like dump but it was so intuitive.